# Нужна ли запятая в конструкции "После [чего-то] (,) необходимо [сделать что-то]"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

> После окончания работ(,) необходимо сообщить заказчику: "Все действия произведены".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не нужна запятая:**

**После окончания работ** необходимо сообщить заказчику: "Все действия произведены!"

Нет причин для обособления  обстоятельства, которое входит в состав основного сообщения.

Comment: А если это обстоятельство более многословное, допустимо ли поставить запятую для лучшего понимания текста?

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Здесь структура основного предложения имеет вид "время -действие", поэтому первую часть обособить сложно даже при ее распространенности. Возьмем, к примеру, такое предложение (отредактированное): Даже после окончания всех речей и после двух бутылок зельтерской воды Андрей Михайлович чувствовал себя настолько бодрым, что далеко не прочь был поболтать с приятелями. Мне кажется, что и здесь запятая не нужна, хотя произносительная пауза присутствует, а обстоятельственный детерминант относится ко всему предложению.